# Parse an unbroken string into words using a dictionary in ansi C

Tags: c, dictionary, parsing, ansi-c

I am a beginning Ansi C student. I have been tasked by my professor to write a program that encrypts, decrypts and parses an unbroken string of characters using a dictionary.

My encryption and decryption algorithms are running perfectly but I am at a loss as to how to parse the string.

Example:

unbroken string:

```
Idontknowwhatto
```

Dictionary:

```
I
dont
know
what
to
do
```

If any body could offer guidance or point me to a resource that may help me understand the process, I would appreciate it.

Thank you

Comment: It's unclear what exactly you're asking (not that we'd just offer up code anyway) but providing a [mcve] would help your question a lot

Comment: What does "using a dictionary" mean? Is it just the associative data structure that maps keys to values, or a repository of words from a natural spoken language?

Comment: Are you trying to turn `Idontknowwhatto` into `I dont know what to`? This is a difficult problem. It's not trivial to implement a naive solution. It's a lot harder to implement an "efficient" one (although even the most efficient solution isn't going to be that efficient). You can even get into a case where there's more than one solution: `penisland`, `therapistfinder`, etc.

Comment: @ikegami - Those examples... mmm...

Comment: The efficient approach would be similar to the dynamic programming approach to solving the [longest common substring problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Longest_common_substring_problem). (Instead of or in addition to lengths, you'd have pointers into a trie of the dictionary.) As a bonus, this would find all possible solutions for the same cost of finding a single solution.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you use a greedy strategy:

- Find the longest word in the dictionary that matches the unbroken string.
- Repeat until you reach the end.
- If you fail to find a match, back up and use the next shorter match. If there are no shorter matches left, then back up another step.

Note: This will find one solution (if it exists). There may be more than one, as pointed out by @ikegami in the comments.

Comment: Why "longest", though, as opposed to "most popular of all possible matches"?

Comment: @Oak, That would be better, but that information is not usually available.

Answer (score 0):

The solution can be to just check the first letter in dictionary. If present check for next set of words starting from the next letter going on and if all letters are found, print it. And again start process with bigger elements of dictionary that matches it and satisfies that whole content is from dictionary. So all combinations can be sorted.

Answer (score 0):

If you're trying to obtain `I don't know what to` from `idontknowwhatto`, the efficient approach would be similar to the dynamic programming approach to solving the [longest common substring problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Longest_common_substring_problem). More specifically, the following is the efficient algorithm:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use utf8;
use open ':std', ':encoding(UTF-8)';
use strict;
use warnings;
use feature qw( say );

use Algorithm::Loops qw( NestedLoops );

my $dict_qfn = '/usr/share/dict/words';

sub add :lvalue {
   my $p = \shift;
   $p = \( $$p->{$_} ) for @_;
   $$p
}

my $trie;
{
   open(my $fh, '<', $dict_qfn)
      or die("Can't open dictionary \"$dict_qfn\": $!\n");

   while (my $word = <$fh>) {
      chomp($word);
      my @key = split(//, lc( $word =~ s/\PL//gr ));
      push @{ add($trie, @key, '') }, $word;
   }
}

for my $phrase (@ARGV) {
   say("$phrase:");

   my @key = split(//, lc( $phrase =~ s/\PL//gr ));

   my @results = map { [] } 0..$#key;
   {
      my @tries = ( $trie ) x (@key+1);
      for my $i (1..@key) {
         for my $j (reverse $i..@key) {
            for my $trie ($tries[$j]) {
               $trie = $tries[$j-1]
                  or next;

               $trie = $trie{ $key[$j-1] }
                  or next;

               if ( my $word_group = $trie->{''} ) {
                  push @{ $results[$j-1] }, [ $i, $word_group ];
               }
            }
         }

         $tries[$i-1] = undef;
      }
   }

   {
      my @todo = [ 0+@key ];
      while (@todo) {
         my ($i, @word_groups) = @{ shift(@todo) };
         if ($i) {
            for (@{ $results[$i-1] }) {
               my ($len, $word_group) = @$_;
               push @todo, [ $i-$len, $word_group, @word_groups ];
            }
         } else {
            my $iter = NestedLoops(\@word_groups);
            while (my @words = $iter->()) {
               say(join(" ", @words));
            }
         }
      }
   }

   say("");
}
```

I'll leave it to you to implement the algorithm in C.